# getting error while destructuring the data from react redux. why it is giving error and how to solve this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

Here is the profile component where i am trying to fetch the user data and getting error in the highlighted part of code. why is userData is undefined ??

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import { getUserProfile } from '../../actions/userActions';
import Styles from './Profile.module.scss';

const Profile = (props) => {
    const userId = props.match.params.id;

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const userLogin = useSelector(state => state.userLogin);
    const {userInfo} = userLogin;

    **const userProfile = useSelector(state => state.userProfile);
    const {loading, error, userData} = userProfile;

    const {posts, data} = userData;**

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!userInfo){
            props.history.push('/login');
        }else{
            dispatch(getUserProfile(userId));
        }
    }, [dispatch,userId])

    return (
        <section>
            <div className={Styles.Container}>
                <h1>{data.userName}</h1>
                <h1>{data.followers.length} followers</h1>
                <h1>{data.following.length} following</h1>
                <h1>{posts.length} posts</h1>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}

export default Profile
```

Here is the Reducer file for userProfile  -

```
export const userProfileReducer = (state={ userData: {}}, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case GET_USER_PROFILE_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true, ...state, }
    
    case GET_USER_PROFILE_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, loading: false, userData: action.payload}
    
    case GET_USER_PROFILE_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload}
    default: return state;
  }
}
```

I am getting this error

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'posts' of 'userData' as it is undefined. Profile
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible for us to know why it's undefined because you don't show where you add the `userProfile` state on your redux store.

I think `userData` "loading" during your render, so for the first render `userData` is undefined.

To avoid this bug, please try to add a if statement :

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        if(!userInfo){
            props.history.push('/login');
        }else{
            dispatch(getUserProfile(userId));
        }
    }, [dispatch,userId])

    if (userData) {
      const {posts, data} = userData;**
      return (
        <section>
            <div className={Styles.Container}>
                <h1>{data.userName}</h1>
                <h1>{data.followers.length} followers</h1>
                <h1>{data.following.length} following</h1>
                <h1>{posts.length} posts</h1>
            </div>
        </section>
      )
    }

    return <div>Loading...</div>
```

Comment: i have also shared reducer file code now it's enough ?

Comment: yeah i have tried and it worked great for me thankyou so much

Comment: So it's only because for the first render your value is undefined.
You can avoid this kind of bug is you using an IF statement at top level of your project to show a "loading" state during the fetch of userData ;)
You can too using the "loading" state given by the reducer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `case GET_USER_PROFILE_FAIL` which returns an object with properties `loading` and `error` and does not copy any other properties from `...state`.  This causes the `userData` property to become `undefined`.

If this is the desired behavior then you need to check for `undefined` in your component and show some sort of error message.

Comment: so what should be in this case ?

Comment: If you just want to suppress this particular error then you can `return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload}` in the reducer, but you're going to show a weird empty screen.

Comment: right before the main `return` in your component, do something like `if ( ! userData && ! loading ) { return <div>{error}</div>; }`